# Is there a tool that helps me understand why a certain row was included in a the result of an SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm maintaining a legacy app where the SQL queries look like the devil's handywork - before I give up and rewrite the whole damn thing I'm hoping to use better tools to do a surgical change :)

I want to know which "WHERE" clause resulted in the inclusion of certain rows when there are a lot of `OR`s. Even better, why certain rows were excluded from the result set.

(Specifically I am using MySQL)

Comment: You might want to get a handle on the basics of writing a SQL string before you get too far into it.  I don't mean to sound like a jerk, but this question is SQL 101.  No, it's PRE-SQL 101.

Comment: (I commented but realized that editing the question will explain my situation better - see new intro)

Comment: @JohnnyBones, it's actually Boolean algebra, which is covered in a lower-division math class or even in high school. :-)

Comment: I have sympathy only because it's a legacy app and I've been there.  Can you post the SQL string?  I won't be able to answer your question with that info alone, but I may be able to point you in the right direction.  I have no idea if it's due to a WHERE clause, a HAVING clause or a JOIN without seeing what the SQL looks like.

Comment: It's more of a recurring thing in this project than a specific problem (I get stuck on fixing a different 1000 characters long SQL query every week and I'm wondering if there's a better way of doing it than my current "spend two hours looking at this monstrosity until the epiphany comes")

Comment: This is one of those questions that usually gets closed by the mods because there's nothing specific about it. The best advice I can give is to strip all the WHERE clause out and just add them back one at a time and re-run the query. You can see what additional rows are coming in with each step. It's more "brute force" than "science", unfortunately.  Honestly, I have at times run 5 simultaneous queries and looked at the results to see what's in one that's not in the other.  It gets messy, but you'll eventually see something in the data.

Comment: So basically the answer to my questions seems to be a solid "no, bruteforce is the way". Boo :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your where condition to a case statement. Break up each 'OR' into it's own column and the result will show you which returned true and false.

I haven't heard of a tool that would do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a variation on Pirion's approach.

Instead of using a case statement, but each `where` clause in the `select` statement.  So, a condition like:

```
select t.*
from t
where A or B or C or D
```

would become:

```
select t.*,
       (Acomp) as A,
       (Bcomp) as B,
       (Ccomp) as C, 
       (Dcomp) as D
from t
where Acomp or Bcomp or Ccomp or Dcomp
```

MySQL has the nice features that a boolean is returns as a `0` (false) or `1` (true).  This will allow you see *all* the conditions that a given row matches.

You might then be able to simplify the logic by removing or combining conditions.

If the conditions are computationally intensive or very long (such as using subqueries), you might want to do this using a subquery:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
       (Acomp) as A,
       (Bcomp) as B,
       (Ccomp) as C, 
       (Dcomp) as D
      from t
     ) t
where A or B or C or D;
```